# Can't update JLabels of minutes and hours for my chronometer in java.swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm trying to make a stopwatch with java.swing and a stopwatch
I have already tried the swing.Timer and TimerTask.
*Could you help me?*

This is the stopwatch.java class

```
    public class Cronometro {
    private int secondi;
    private int minuti;
    private int ore;
    private boolean state=true;
    
    public Cronometro(){
        
    }
    
    public void crono(JLabel s, JLabel m, JLabel h, ActionEvent evt){
        state=true;
        
        Thread t = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                for(;;){
                    if(state==true){
                       try{
                           sleep(10);
                           secondi++;
                           if(secondi>60){
                               secondi=0;
                               minuti++;
                               
                           }
                           if(minuti>60){
                               secondi=0;
                               minuti=0;
                               ore++;
                           }
                           s.setText(" :"+secondi);
                           m.setText(" : "+minuti);
                           h.setText(""+ore);
                       } catch(Exception e){
                           
                       }
                    }
                    else{
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        
        t.start();
    }
    
    public void setState(boolean state){
        this.state=state;
    }
    
}
```

The gui/main.java was generated almost all by netbeans

Comment: There is also the GUI.java code: https://srcb.in/CU0yc59Ba5

Comment: Don't block the Event Dispatch Thread.

Comment: 1. Swing is a single Thread library. All painting tasks are executed in the Event Dispatcher Thread ([EDT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)). 
Running long processes (such as sleep or infinite loop) on the EDT makes this thread busy, so it does not do other things like updating the gui. The gui becomes unresponsive (freezes). Use a Swing timer instead of loop which contains sleep. 2. Do not post links to code. Instead post [mre].

Comment: You are making Swing calls, such as `s.setText(" :"+secondi);` off of the event dispatch thread, a no-no. Either read [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and use a SwingWorker (with its publish/process method pair) or use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can use a Swing Timer to run `update` every second:

```
class Cronometro {
    private int secondi;
    private int minuti;
    private int ore;
    private boolean state=true;
    private Timer timer;

    private final JLabel s, m,  h;

    public Cronometro(JLabel s, JLabel m, JLabel h) {
        this.s = s;
        this.m = m;
        this.h = h;
    }

    public void crono(JLabel s, JLabel m, JLabel h){
        state=true;
        if(timer != null) {
            timer.stop();
        }

        timer = new Timer(1000, e->update());
        timer.start();
    }

    public void update(){

        if(! state) return;
        secondi++;
        if(secondi>60){
            secondi=0;
            minuti++;
        }

        if(minuti>60){
            secondi=0;
            minuti=0;
            ore++;
        }
        s.setText(" :"+secondi);
        m.setText(" : "+minuti);
        h.setText(""+ore);
    }

    public void setState(boolean state){
        this.state=state;
    }
}
```

Side note: to improve the application structure introduce a model class that encapsulates the needed information (seconds, minutes, hours). Share this model between `Cronometro` and the GUI.